# required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found, but configs were given

Tags: java, email, spring-boot, javabeans

I want to send email using JavaMailSender in a SpringBoot gradle project, but I got error that the configure of the email didn't work.

```html
17:44:47.004 [main ,] DEBUG o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
 at com.quduoduo.userbackend.UserbackendApplication.main(UserbackendApplication.java:18)
17:44:47.005 [main ,] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.quduoduo.userbackend.service.impl.EmailServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52323', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

There are the email configuration in bootstrap.properties. I gave the host, port, protocol and username&password.

```
spring.mail.default-encoding=utf-8
spring.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.smtp.port=587
spring.mail.username=xxxx
spring.mail.password=xxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=3000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

And the code in EmailServiceImpl.java. The @autowired didn't work.

```
private final TemplateEngine templateEngine;
private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

@Autowired
public EmailServiceImpl(TemplateEngine templateEngine,
                        JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
}
```

There are the dependencies in the build.gradle file.

```html
dependencies {
    compile group:"cn.com.antube", name:"antube-commons", version:"0.0.3-SNAPSHOT", changing:true
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin"
    compile('io.projectreactor:reactor-core')
    compile('org.redisson:redisson:3.7.5')
    compile('io.vavr:vavr-jackson:0.9.2')
    compile('com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.49')
    compile('org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.4.0')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15')
    compile('com.aliyun:aliyun-java-sdk-dysmsapi:1.0.0')
    compile('com.aliyun:aliyun-java-sdk-core:4.0.8')
    compile("org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.3.2")
    compile('com.auth0:java-jwt:3.0.2')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.0.4.RELEASE')
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.4')
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1-groovy-2.4')
}
```

Could you tell me how to solve this bug? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpringBoot Application Startup Failed due to autowire JavaMailSender - version 2.0.0-snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708272/springboot-application-startup-failed-due-to-autowire-javamailsender-version-2)

Comment: no, not the same. I did offer the config like the smtp.host and smtp.port, the question you given didn't offer. But still thankyou. @Arnaud

Comment: Start your application with `--debug` and you'll get a detailed report that tells you exactly why `MailAutoConfiguration` isn't activating.

Comment: Please show you pom.xml, you may missing some dependencies.

Comment: dependencies added :) @IanLim

Comment: Have you try to change compile group: to compile like the rest of the spring-boot-starters ?

Comment: I tried and it didn't work :( @IanLim

Comment: The exception info is : 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}  @chrylis

Comment: (1) Please make sure your dependancies are all align to 2.1.1. I spotted spring-boot-starter-test to be the wrong version.

Comment: (2) Try something simple like following this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email to make sure it works first in your environment

Comment: (3) Take a look at this guide to see if your build.gradle is correct https://guides.gradle.org/building-spring-boot-2-projects-with-gradle/

Comment: I'm aware of what the exception is, and I gave instructions on how to produce the required debug output.

Comment: Thank you, @IanLim, using step (2), problem solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks I think it's because of server configuration. I'm giving code for both Gradle and Maven(I know you are using Gradle but the same problem can be faced by someone who is using Maven so I'm providing solutions for both)

For Gradle, add these to your application.properties file and these

```
spring.mail.username=youremail@domain.com
spring.mail.password=yourpassword
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.port= 25
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.outh=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

And for Maven, add this to your server.xml file:

```
<mailSession description="" from="" host="127.0.0.1" jndiName="" mailSessionID="" transportProtocol="smtp" user="youremail@domain.com" password="yourpassword">
                   <property name="mail.smtp.auth" value="true"/>
                   <property name="mail.smtp.port" value="25"/>
               </mailSession>
```

Hope this helps!!